# Deleted the apk key by mistake

Tags: android

I have put up an app in the market..but I have to update the app..but my mistake i deleted the old apk and have made changes to the code and when I try uploading the app it says I must have the same key..what should I do now?

Comment: Don't have the old keystore, not even in some old mail attachment? Then you are going to need to upload as a new application.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is absolutely no way to update your application. Sorry.

You should publish you new update as a new Application with a new key and a new package. Also update the description of your old app and tell your user about the new app.

If you have a webview loaded from external web server, try to inform on that page, too.

Basically, that is all you can do.

Lessons learned: Backup your key the next time!

Comment: This is all correct, but one very important step was missed: the old app should be unpublished so that new users won't see (or install) the defunct version. Existing users will still be able to see it in the Market / Play Store, so they will see the updated description pointing to the new version. (The exception to this is if your app is highly ranked, you might want to leave the old version visible for a brief period, but it should still be unpublished before long.)

Answer (score 3):

You will have to upload a new application to the market. There is nothing else you can do.

Like they said at the last Google IO - Even if you know Andy Rubin personally, even *he* can't do anything.