# minSdkVersion breaking program

Tags: android

So whenever I add

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion = "7"></uses-sdk>
```

my application refuses to work properly. The UI is miniature (the font is small and the buttons are smaller than usual). I tried changing the minversion from 7-15 and none of them worked. My phone is on 4.0.4 and whenever I take out

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion>
```

it works perfectly. Sadly google market requires this, and I can't upload the application not working. Any ideas? If I need to give more information just ask, thank you so much!

The application is mainly an XML app, such that there is no graphical interface, just native buttons, and such. I am using the `Theme.Holo.Light` theme though. Thank you!

Comment: source of layout, manifest, logcat? :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easy fix is likely to set `minSdkVersion` to 1; this should give you the same behavior as leaving it out, but allow you to upload your app to the Play store.

The better solution would be to set it to an appropriate value based on what APIs you use and testing it on various devices, and adjust your layouts to work appropriately.

Comment: Perfect, so now that is working, but now it says "The apk must be signed with the same certificates as the previous version." When I developed version 1.0 it was on my old computer that is now gone. Forever. All I had was the source code from version 1.0, and I just finished version 2.0. Why won't it just let me upload it? It's the same app just newer? Is there a way around this?

Comment: @Zargle You need to hang onto your release key for dear life. Unfortunately, you'll have to upload the new version as a new app: http://stackoverflow.com/q/7545548/1427098

Comment: Sad day... Thank you so much for the help! I would give you a vote, but I'm not high enough.

Comment: The app is on the Play store but now it says it's only compatible for anyone under 4.0 so I don't even see it even though I developed it on my 4.0.4 device.....