# Application not showing up in Google Play searches for 4.x devices

Tags: android

I recently posted about the Play store not letting me publish my app without a minSdkVersion, but whenever I set it to anything above "1" my app just doesn't work ( [minSdkVersion breaking program](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11441701/minsdkversion-breaking-program) ).

So this guy suggested to just set my minSdkVersion to 1, which worked. But now when I submitted my app even though the developer site says:

```
API level: 1-16+
Supported screens: normal-xlarge
OpenGL textures: all
```

But [the app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.unparalleledsoftware.applist&feature=more_from_developer#?t=W251bGwsMSwxLDEwMiwiY29tLnVucGFyYWxsZWxlZHNvZnR3YXJlLmFwcGxpc3QiXQ) only shows it supports Android under 4.x, I developed it on my 4.0.4 device. I tried searching around and I found that some people have problems with services messing up the phones it supports, so I deleted all of my services, because I don't really need any for this version of the app to submit. And it still didn't work. So I don't know what else to do, here is my AndroidManifest.xml if it helps... Thank you so much!

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     package="com.unparalleledsoftware.applist"
     android:versionCode="4"
     android:versionName="2.01" >

    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="1"/>


 <application 
     android:icon="@drawable/icon"
     android:label="@string/app_name" 
     android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light">


    <activity android:name="com.unparalleledsoftware.applist.applist"
              android:label="@string/app_name">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <receiver  android:process=":remote" android:name="com.unparalleledsoftware.applist.AlarmReceiver"></receiver>
 </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: Have you tried setting a targetSDK? Why set minSDK to 1? What SDK are you developing against? The reason why it is breaking may have something to do with using classes that aren't available to a user. Can I get a stack trace?

Comment: Sorry I'm new, what is a stack trace? Whenever I set a targetSDK, or maxSDK (or setting minSDK to anything above 1) my application breaks, the UI is miniature (the font is small and the buttons are smaller than usual). I tried changing the minversion from 7-15 and none of them worked. My phone is on 4.0.4 and whenever I take out the uses-sdk or change it to minSDK 1 it works perfectly.

Comment: ...what are you building the project against....to find out...right click on the project in the project explorer -->properties-->select Android on the left panel.  On the right what is selected under Project Build Target?

Comment: @Zargle If your application breaks by using the SDK normally, you're doing something very, very wrong. Chances are you're creating layouts at fixed pixel sizes (instead of device-independent pixels -- DP) and not using the various resource folders for different screen densities.

Comment: 4.1 (http://cl.ly/1O2N2E1V1F2i3b3T1i3E)

Comment: @kcoppock how do I fixed it and know what is actually breaking the program? Sad times, can I just create a new project? or will I not be able to update the application and have to create a new application on the market because of the keystone and such?

Comment: You can update it, you'll just have to revise your layouts most likely. That sort of thing is far outside the scope of this question though, go to http://d.android.com and read through the basic layout and multiple screen support documentation.

Comment: Now nothing is working, even the name on of the app isn't working, it just says "MainActivity" rather than "App List" even though the AndroidManifest.xml shows it being App list... WTH... Why does nothing work? I created a bran new project, just copied the Strings, and the activity_main.xml which is just buttons and a textview, and the source code. Changed nothing else, even created new java files for the source code. Why does it break the second the minSDK is greater than 1, or the target is there?