# Application not showing up in Google Play for 4.x devices

Tags: android, android-market-filtering

I recently posted about the Play store not letting me publish my app without a minSdkVersion, but whenever I set it to anything above "1" my app just doesn't work ([minSdkVersion breaking program](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11441701/minsdkversion-breaking-program)).

So this guy suggested to just set my minSdkVersion to 1, which worked. But now when I submitted my app even though the developer site says:

```
API level: 1-16+
Supported screens: normal-xlarge
OpenGL textures: all
```

But [the app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.unparalleledsoftware.applist&feature=more_from_developer#?t=W251bGwsMSwxLDEwMiwiY29tLnVucGFyYWxsZWxlZHNvZnR3YXJlLmFwcGxpc3QiXQ) only shows it supports Android under 4.x, I developed it on my 4.0.4 device. I tried searching around and I found that some people have problems with services messing up the phones it supports, so I deleted all of my services, because I don't really need any for this version of the app to submit. And it still didn't work. So I don't know what else to do, here is my AndroidManifest.xml if it helps... I've been trying to figure out why my application isn't working for a week now, still nothing. I have tried setting a targetSdkVersion to something like 14, my application still breaks. I cleaned out my code, taking everything out of the already short, 200 lines, application, and it still isn't working. Is there something I can't use in an android application 4.0 that I am using in my application? or is it just my AndroidManifest? Thank you so much!

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.unparalleledsoftware.app.list"
android:versionCode="5"
android:versionName="2.02" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="1" />

<application
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_main" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

I should note,I am using the Theme.Holo.Light, but even if I change it to DeviceDefault it doesn't work.

Edit:

I googled the app on my friends Samsung Galaxy S3 (it didn't show up in the Play Store on his phone), when I installed by googling the app and hitting the "install" button on google and it opened in the Google Play store and was able to install. When I did the same on my phone, Galaxy Note, it opened in the Google Play Store, but then said "Not compatible." Why? They are both on the same version of OS. Why is mine not compatible, nor the One X compatible, but the Samsung Galaxy S3 worked...?

Edit: I get these errors/problems when compiling with a targetSdkVersion, http://pastebin.com/mxgWNLdM

Comment: It shows up fine for my Galaxy Nexus (4.1) and Xoom (4.0.3).

Comment: Application downloads and installed fine on my Nexus S (4.0.4)

Comment: I have a Samsung Galaxy Note, and my friend has a HTC One X and neither of them show the application. And, if I go onto the website, it shows that neither my device (the one I developed it on) and the HTC One X is compatible... I can't even find it on the device I developed it on :(

Answer (score 0):

It's showing up as "Requires Android 1.0 and up" on my end, and there's nothing wrong with your manifest either. It'll show up on all devices.

You should, however, avoid using Holo themes if you're targeting devices running versions of Android prior to 3.0. The best practice is to create two themes - one for API levels 1-10 and one for API level 11+, and make sure that the v11 one is using a Holo theme as the parent style.

Comment: I have a Samsung Galaxy Note, and my friend has a HTC One X and neither of them show the application. And, if I go onto the website, it shows that neither my device (the one I developed it on) and the HTC One X is compatible... I can't even find it on the device I developed it on :(

Comment: If anything then it's a problem with those devices and not the application. Also make sure that you haven't excluded any devices in the Developer Console.

Comment: I haven't excluded any devices, no. :'(

Comment: Sorry. There's absolutely nothing wrong with it, so I don't know why you're experiencing issues.

Answer (score 0):

Your Manifest file only has a minSdk setting which is odd/bad since according to the documentation if you don't set a targetSdk, it will default to the minSdk level.[Android Manifest - Uses SDK element](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-sdk-element.html). The thing is that an API setting of 1 is really old and I wouldn't be surprised that Market/Play has issues. If you developed this on ICS, you should really have a targetSdk. Also if it was developed for API level 14, you should have a supports-screen element as well.

At worst, I would create a new project and copy over that manfest file for any missing elements. If you are still having issues with a targetSdk and supports-screens, turn on verbose build messages and see if anything looks wrong.

Comment: While posting your errors is good, you don't say if you've tried to correct each error one by one. The first one looks like an missing icon resource, the second one 'missing Android-8' can easily be found by a google search. I'm afraid few will assist as it could be your project or your environment.

Comment: @Marrison Chang I fixed all of the problems, apparently the debugger compiles all of the errors from all of my other problems. I fixed all of the problem in this program. So all of the compiler bugs are fixed, and the program still isn't working. Is there any program that can tell me why things aren't working?

Answer (score 0):

I you posted your complete Manifest file above, then I suggest adding `<supports-screen>` entry (above `<applicaion>`) to it, like this:

```
<supports-screens android:largeScreens="true" 
                  android:normalScreens="true"
                  android:smallScreens="true"
                  android:anyDensity="true" />
```

Lack of it (if not intentional) causes application to be not available for any device it should, due to Play's filtering mechanism.